# Markdown title contains symbols like [ ]

Tags: markdown

How can I write code to include "[ ]" in the title

### [image]

Here the parentheses are white, indicating that the parentheses cannot appear in the title. In fact, the compilation fails.

Comment: This is not exactly Markdown, it is "front matter" from your blogging platform (you're using Hugo or Jekyll maybe?). Please post the command you are using to "compile" and what the error message is. You can also try putting a \ before a character like `[` which has another purpose.

Comment: I using Hexo.When I add a \ before [,then my blog ttite appear the character\\[C\\],this is not what i want.`YAMLException: can not read a block mapping entry; a multiline key may not be an implicit key at line 2, column 5:
    date: 2020-03-09 19:41:39
        ^
`

Comment: Try putting quotation marks around the title and date (after the colon).

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't.

"Front matter" or "metadata" (as it is sometimes called) is not Markdown, but an add-on. Most Markdown system's which add support for front matter do so with a preprocessor which removes the front matter from the document before passing the document to the Markdown parser. Therefore, the content of the front matter is not processed as Markdown. Unfortunately, that means that front matter can only contain plain text.

That said, you might be able to use raw HTML in your front matter. However, I would expect that when the data contained in the front matter is passed to whatever templating system is being used, the raw HTML will be escaped, negating any benefit. YMMV.